# Edit headers of MultiPartEntity

Tags: java, android, httprequest, multipartform-data, multipartentity

I'm making a XML + image post in my Android application with a `MultiPartEntity` and every thing is good except the server that I'm posting to requires me to set the `Content-Type`of the HTTP post to `application/soap+xml; charset="utf-8"`

So how do I get to change it from this...

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.193:1234
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=XR43mUmjvTb58T7crHhgj83C84qmZO_9k0-s
Content-Length: 28150
Connection: Keep-Alive

--XR43mUmjvTb58T7crHhgj83C84qmZO_9k0-s
...
```

to this

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.193:1234
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 28150
Connection: Keep-Alive

--XR43mUmjvTb58T7crHhgj83C84qmZO_9k0-s
...
```

This is probably not the correct way to post it but I have to, than it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to do this and it's simply by adding a header to the `HttpPost` object.

```
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        entity.addPart(xml);
        entity.addPart(image);

        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=\"utf-8\"");
        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```